# Why is .always method callback function of $.ajax() not executed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ladda

I'm using Ladda to show a waiting animation while a AJAX call is executed. I use the Ladda start() method to start the animation on button and I need to stop it when job is done but the callback of always method of $.ajax() is not executed, why?

```
let l = Ladda.create(this);
l.start();
$.ajax({
  url: molarisk_public.ajaxurl,
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    action: 'user_send_verification',
    _nonce: molarisk_public.nonce,
    log: log,
    pwd: pwd,
    ver_type: ver_type
  },
  success: function(result) {
    switch (result) {
      case 'signin_attempt_sent':
        output_p.removeClass('text-danger');
        output_p.addClass('text-success');
        output_p.text('Codice generato, controlla la posta!');
        break;
      case 'email_verification_sent':
        output_p.removeClass('text-danger');
        output_p.addClass('text-success');
        output_p.text('Link di verifica inviato, controlla la posta!');
        break;
      case 'email_unverified':
        output_p.removeClass('text-success');
        output_p.addClass('text-danger');
        let unverified = 'Non hai ancora verificato il tuo indirizzo e-mail. Esegui prima la verifica dell’indirizzo cliccando sul link che ti è stato inviato oppure <button type="button" class="as-a-link send-link-btn" id="test">richiedi un nuovo link di verifica</button>.';
        output_p.html(unverified);
        break;
      default:
        output_p.removeClass('text-success');
        output_p.addClass('text-danger');
        output_p.text(result);
    }
    //l.stop();
  },
  always: function() {
    l.stop();
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, sorry for the stupid question, here it's late and I'm tired... I need to user `complete` and not `always`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using the properties of a settings object in `$.ajax`. Therefore the property name should be `complete`.

```js
$.ajax({
  // other properties...
  success: function(result) {
    // your logic
  },
  complete: function() {
    l.stop();
  }
});
```

You seem to be confusing it with the `always()` method on a deferred object. To use that, chain the method call after `$.ajax()`:

```js
$.ajax({
  // request properties...
}).done(function(result) {
  switch(result) {
    // your logic
  }
}).always(function() {
  l.stop();
});
```